# Import processing module from QGIS into Python Window of ArcCatalog

Tags: arcpy, pyqgis, qgis-processing, arccatalog, python-window

It is possible to import processing module from QGIS and run it in Python Window of ArcCatalog?

I tried in QGIS

```
 import sys
 output = sys.path
```

and copy output to ArcGIS Python console:

```
import sys
for x in output :
     sys.path.append(x)
```

then I tried to import:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui
import PyQt4.QtCore
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
import processing
```

For example `import processing` return error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing   \__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
 from processing.tools.dataobjects import *
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 29, in <module>
  from qgis.core import *
 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed:Can`t find the specified module.
```

Comment: It looks like you've cut off the last part of the Python error. Is there not a file name listed after the DLL load failed?

Comment: You have set your python path `sys.path` so python can find the qgis modules, but haven't set the path `os.environ['path']` so windows can find the DLL/pyd